# Can we used a classifier from rapid miner in weka?

Tags: weka, rapidminer, text-classification

i am working on text classification in weka. I want to use a classifier from rapidminer. I just saw the "weka.jar" in rapidminer lib directory which may mean that we can use some cross functionality.

Can we use a classifier or functionality from rapid miner whereas some other functionalities from weka ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't!!
Weka is not covering that functionality.

Comment: thanx for passing through, we can do it actually, there is a plugin for rapidminer which enables us to use weka classifier in rapidminer, i am using that plugin which satisfies my need...!! :)

Comment: HUmmmm, sorry... maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to run rapidminer processes directly in Weka.

Comment: @andresram12 no problem, no its not what i wanted...!!